# how to get similar search results in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to search by words similarity or even if someone made a typo.

For example if anyone searches with `picadilly` correct one is `piccadilly`, It should get the result.

I had tried by searching by removing a char from last until 3 chars left using PHP, for example `picadilly` `picadill` `picadil` `picadi` `picad` `pica` `pic`

It's working but I am also getting unwanted results (due to shorten of keyword to 3 chars) which aren't similar, Also don't think it is a good way, Is there any better approach ?

Table Structure & Data:

```
+----+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| id | name                      | address                                              |
+----+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | Bethnal Green Station     | Bethnal Green Tube Station, London, E2 0ET           |
|  2 | Westminster Station       | Westminster Tube Station, London, SW1A 2JR           |
|  3 | Goldhawk Road Station     | Goldhawk Road Tube Station, London, W12 8EG          |
|  4 | Piccadilly Circus Station | Piccadilly Circus Tube Station, London, W1J 9HP      |
|  5 | Ravenscourt Park Station  | Ravenscourt Park Tube Station, London, W6 0JJ        |
|  6 | Barons Court Station      | Barons Court Tube Station, London, W14 9EA           |
|  7 | Charing Cross Station     | Charing Cross Tube & Train Station, London, WC2N 6RQ |
|  8 | Hammersmith Station       | Hammersmith Tube Station, London, W6 8AB             |
|  9 | Embankment Station        | Embankment Tube Station, London, WC2N 6NS            |
| 10 | Leicester Square Station  | Leicester Square Tube Station, London, WC2H 0AP      |
+----+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `stations`
WHERE name like '%picadilly%'
   OR name like '%picadill%'
   OR name like '%picadil%'
   OR name like '%picadi%'
   OR name like '%picad%'
   OR name like '%pica%'
   OR name like '%pic%'
```

Answer (score 2):

You should *start* by looking into the [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) algorithm. It assigns a "sound" to a given string which can be used to find closely matching words.

It's particularly suited to English text but, provided you can live with that, it's not too bad.

For example, both `Pax` and `packs` generate `P200`, `heiress` and `hares` both give `H620` and, for your question, both `Picadilly` and `Piccadilly` give `P234`.

So, if you store the Soundex code alongside the word in a database, and indexed on that code, you could very quickly get a list of close matches.

Comment: Thanks for your response!, but how can I add wildcard in this like my table field contains "Piccadilly Circus Station" and I need to search with "picadilly"